# Notifying controller that a key's been pressed, from view?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm making a game, and I have the following main classes

Main controller class:

```
public class Manager implements Runnable {
private boolean running;
private Thread thread;

private MasterRenderer window;

private PlayerCharacter player;


private Map map;

public Manager() {
    window = new MasterRenderer();
    player = new PlayerCharacter(0, 0, Entity.FACING_DOWN, "Pepe", 0, 1, 2);
    map = new Map();

}

public void initialize() {
    window.setPlayerRenderer(new PlayerRenderer(player));
    window.setMapRenderer(new MapRenderer(map));
    window.setTerrainRenderer(new TerrainRenderer(new Terrain(0, 0, Entity.FACING_DOWN, "arbol", false)));

    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);

    thread.start();
}

public void run() {
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    double delta = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    int ticks = 0;
    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1) {
            tick(delta);
            ticks++;
            delta--;
            frames++;
            render();
        }
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("Frames: " + frames + "\tTicks: " + ticks);

            frames = ticks = 0;
        }
    }
}

public void tick(double delta) {

}

public void render() {
    window.render();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Manager manager = new Manager();
    manager.initialize();
}
}
```

Main view class:

```
public class MasterRenderer extends Canvas implements KeyListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WIDTH = 640;
public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH * 3 / 4;
public static final String TITLE = "The legend of Finn";

private JFrame frame;
private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;

private PlayerRenderer playerR;
private MapRenderer mapR;
private TerrainRenderer terrainR;

public MasterRenderer() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

    frame = new JFrame();

    addKeyListener(this);
    frame.setTitle(TITLE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    requestFocus();
}

public void render() {
    bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    playerR.render(g);
    mapR.render(g);
    terrainR.render(g);

    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}

public void setMapRenderer(MapRenderer mapR) {
    this.mapR = mapR;
}

public void setPlayerRenderer(PlayerRenderer playerR) {
    this.playerR = playerR;
}

public void setTerrainRenderer(TerrainRenderer terrainR) {
    this.terrainR = terrainR;
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int i=e.getKeyCode();

    System.out.println("Key pressed!!");
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}
}
```

I've organize the code this way, because I'm trying to really stick to MVC (besides, putting the keyListener in the manager class now is a bit of a pain in the butt). Is there any simple way to notify Manager when MasterRenderer registers a key press?

Comment: Take a look at my article, [Retro Snake Game](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=768), to see an example of a Swing application that uses the MVC pattern, and also uses Key Bindings for the keyboard input.

Comment: ....................hello?

Answer (score 0):

Your View has no Control reference within it, and no methods for registering listeners, and without this, I don't see how the view will communicate with the control. I see you have two possible solutions:

1. Pass the Control reference into the view, and have the view call methods of the control when it wants to notify it of a state change, or
2. set up a mechanism, such as a SwingPropertyChangeSupport mechanism, that will allow the control to listener for state changes. If you go this route, then you have to call the approprate `fireXxx(...)` methods of the support.

Luckily many Swing and AWT components already have mechanisms for number 2 above, and I suggest that you do just this: have your control register a PropertyChangeListener with your Canvas object (better if it were a JPanel!), and then in your KeyListener a `firePropertyChange(...)` method notifying the control of the state change.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;    

public class MyControl implements Runnable, PropertyChangeListener {

    public MyControl() {
        // TODO finish
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {

        // this is only one of potentially many properties that the control can listen to
        if (MyView.KEY_PRESSED.equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
            // respond to the key pressed code
            System.out.println("KeyCode is: " + pcEvt.getNewValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Finish!
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        // create both view and control
        MyControl control = new MyControl();
        MyView view = new MyView();

        // now wire the control to listen to the view
        view.addPropertyChangeListener(MyView.KEY_PRESSED, control);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyControl");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(view);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }


}

class MyView extends JPanel {
    // constant for PropertyChangeListener use:
    public static final String KEY_PRESSED = "key pressed";
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;

    public MyView() {
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
        addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // get the keycode pressed
            int newValue = e.getKeyCode();

            // ** notify any listeners that this key has been pressed **
            firePropertyChange(KEY_PRESSED, null, newValue);
        }

    }

}
```